# Determining a radius convergence of a power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} x^{3n+1} $$

Is there an immediate way to determine $R=1$?

Comment: What would count as immediate?

Comment: Differentiate term-by-term...

Comment: I could the classic cauchy hadamard formula but I wonder if one can figure out immediately $R=1$..

Comment: It may help to consider the derivative for which the summation can be done. Its radius of convergence obviously is 1.

Comment: @Urgje, I see: because the radius of convergence preserve after taking the derivative. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some way how to determine $R=1$, for example:

1. [Ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) We have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(3n+1)x^3}{(3n+4)}=|x^3|$$

So series converges for $|x|<1$.

2. [Root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) We have:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|^3\sqrt[n]{3n+1}=|x|^3$$